# prevent template instantiation when template argument is zero

Tags: c++, templates, boost, c++03

I have a templated class

```
template< std::size_t Size >
class Buffer
{
....
};
```

I'd like to prevent instantiation of this template when the Size argument is zero. i.e. generate a compiler warning for the following.

```
Buffer< 0 > buf;
```

but all other variants would work.

```
Buffer< 10 > buf;
```

I'm looking at using boost::enable_if_c but I don't understand how to get it working.

--Update--
I can't use any c++11 features, unfortunately

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Utilizing `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` might be even easier:

```
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>

template< std::size_t Size >
class Buffer
{
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(Size != 0);
};


int main()
{
    Buffer<0> b; //Won't compile
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 + Accepted : As my compiler doesn't support static_assert and I originally wanted a boost answer :)

Answer (score 10):

Simply specialize the template to a state that cannot be instatiated:

```
template <>
class Buffer<0>;
```

That way the class cannot be constructed. Usage will result in:
`error: aggregate ‘Buffer<0> buf’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined`

Comment: There is no need to make constructor `private`. Making the class body-less, i.e.`template<> class Buffer<0>;` is sufficient to generate an error.

Comment: @iammilind: Right, I forgot about the simple declaration without definition. Edited to the shorter version.

Answer (score 6):

If your compiler support it, try [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert):

```
template< std::size_t Size >
class Buffer
{
    static_assert(Size != 0, "Size must be non-zero");

    // ...
};
```

Comment: +1 I agree that this would be the better approach if the compiler supports static_assert, however my compiler doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stddef.h>

typedef ptrdiff_t Size;

template< Size size >
class Buffer
{
    static_assert( size > 0, "" );
};

int main()
{
#ifdef  ZERO
    Buffer<0>   buf;
#else
    Buffer<1>   buf;
#endif
}
```

Comment: This will [fail](http://ideone.com/Dk5o2) `Buffer<-1>` also; which is not the requirement.

Comment: @iammilind: it the OP desires to support buffer size -1, then he will hopefully find it easy to change the condition from `>` to `!=`.

Comment: Yup, and interestingly the [other way](http://ideone.com/WGAv3) is to simply `typdef unsigned long Size;`, so all invocation except the `Buffer<0>` shall pass.

Comment: @iammilind: anyone reading this commentary should better note that in 64 bit Windows `unsigned long` is only 32 bits, while array sizes can be larger. apart from the specific unsigned type (better make that a `size_t` for generality, when unsigned type is a requirement) there are also problems in general with using unsigned types for numbers. on some DSP platforms those problems are outweighted by other concerns, but for general programming, it's a good idea to reserve unsigned types for bit-level stuff and modulo arithmetic.

Comment: *"please explain your downvote, so that others can more easily ignore your future downvotes and comments"* - Well, if he had explained it reasonably, there wouldn't be any reason to ignore his future downvotes and comments per se, apart from taking downvotes personally maybe. *iammilind* already gave some reason (not implying him or me to be the downvoter).

Comment: It's especially difficult to take that notion seriously considering that the questioner uses `size_t` for the type of the template parameter. This is the "unsigned types? I hates them!" version of the questioner's code -- use a signed type but exclude negative values. Obviously the rest of the class might have to be updated to account for that, but since that isn't shown in the question, Alf can't demonstrate it.

Answer (score 0):

#### `std::enable_if`

```
template <std::size_t N, typename = typename std::enable_if<!!N>::type>
class Matrix {};
```

#### `static_assert`:

```
template <std::size_t N>
class Matrix
{
    static_assert(N, "Error: N is 0");
};
```